# PhantomJS: How to access global functions and variables?

Tags: javascript, scope, phantomjs, global

I am trying to run a .js through PhantomJS and use some global functions or variables from within the page context.

Here is a minimal example:

```js
var page = require('webpage').create(); // or: var page = new WebPage();

// reroute page's console to global console
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) { console.log(msg) }

function Foo(x) { return "bar"+x }

page.open( 'https://www.example.com/', function(){

    console.log(Foo(1)); // works OK

    page.evaluate( function(){

        console.log('test'); // works OK (message appears because we rerouted 
                             // the page's console to global console output)

        console.log(Foo(2)); // does NOT work, Foo is unknown
    });

    console.log(Foo(3)); // works OK
    phantom.exit();

});
```

Note how the `Foo()` function is not known within the context of the page's `evaluate()` function.

I've tried numerous approaches, such as doing `page.Foo2 = Foo;` right below the definition of `Foo` and then within the `evaluate` context I call `Foo2(2)`, but nope.

Or `page.Foo2 = function(x) { return Foo(x) }` but again, to no avail. Also not by calling `this.Foo2(2)` instead of just `Foo2(2)` (if that even makes sense).

How do I access functions or variables outside the `page` scope?

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a function in the sandbox context:

```
page.open( 'https://www.example.com/', function(){

    page.evaluate( function(){

        function Foo(x) { return "bar"+x }

        console.log(Foo(2));
    });

    phantom.exit();
});
```

Or, if you need to use it in the global context too, you can send it into the sandbox:

```
function Foo(x) { return "bar"+x }

page.open( 'https://www.example.com/', function(){

    console.log(Foo(1));

    page.evaluate( function(Foo){

        console.log(Foo(2));

    }, Foo);

    console.log(Foo(3));

    phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: Yes but that's not what I need, I have global functions which I also want to call from within the page / sandbox context.

Comment: Thanks but no, in most situations I cannot simply re-declare the same function within the page scope. For example, what if I want to do this:
`var f = require('fs').open('test.txt','w'); f.write('hello'); f.close();` to write a text file. This works outside page.evaluate, but not inside (doesn't know `require`). Here I just write "hello" but suppose I want to save the page's html content or something else that I can only obtain inside `page.evaluate`.

Comment: You should have explained your intentions better in your question. Of course browser wouldn't be able to `f.write`, but you *can* pass such a function to the sandbox and use it from there. So, technically the answer is correct (at least considering the question).

Comment: As to what you want, why even do that? Why not just get data from `page.evaluate` and write it to disk in the global context?

Comment: Yes, in this particular minimal example I could just output the result. This doesn't apply if I want to write or append more complex data from within the evaluate sandbox. Or do other things than writing files, such as sending keypress events like `page.sendEvent('keypress',page.event.key.Return)`. Right now I can only do this from outside, but for some reason I cannot pass the `f` (file) object or `page` object or `sendEvent` function closure into the sandbox. I'm even surprised you can pass on the short example `Foo` function, but that doesn't work if Foo calls other "outside" functions.

Comment: To clarify, in your other comment you said "but you can pass such a function to the sandbox and use it from there" but no, unfortunately this is not possible. I cannot use the file object and do `f.write` *inside* the evaluate function.

Comment: `for some reason I cannot pass the f (file) object or page object or sendEvent function closure into the sandbox` Because you can pass in/out only simple **serializable** non-native functions/objects. I think you still misunderstand what a sandbox is. It's like a virtual machine. You don't expect a VM to execute arbitrary programs on a host machine at will, do you?

Comment: Sure, I understand that (that's why I was surprised the Foo example worked) but besides not passing them into the function, I also cannot instantiate such objects within the sandbox. Sending events, such as `keypress` for example, would make perfect sense to do within the sandbox. Yet I don't see a way to access the `page.sendEvent` function within the sandbox.